# Create a loop that reaches end then reverses back

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to create a for loop that prints numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. Once reaching the end the loop should reverse back starting from 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. The output only goes through the elements and then ends, it doesn't reverse back. Is there a better way to code this, I am fairly new to programming and working with arrays and loops. Any help will be appreciated.

```
int num = 0;
        
        int[] arrayNumber = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }; 
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber.length; ) {
            if (i < 8) {
                i++;
            } else {
                i--;
            }
            num = arrayNumber[i];
            System.out.print(num);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 Loops for each display like this below:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};   
//this one fo         
for (int n: numbers) {
        System.out.println(n);
}
//this one for the Reverse display
for(int i = (numbers.length-1);  i>=0;i--){
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do an infinite loop (in python) :

```
i = 0;
test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
goesdown = False
while True:
  print(test[i])
  i += -1 if goesdown == True else 1
  if(test[i] == test[-1]):
    goesdown = True
  if(test[i] == test[0]):
    goesdown = False
```